# Memory cached generic list removing without effect cached list

Tags: c#, memcached, generic-list

I am trying remove one item from my list.BUT, I am getting the list from cache. 
 After this I am removing one item in my fuction. This removing effect my cached list.If I try again to get cached list from cache in another page. Removed item is missing how is this possible ?

example ,

```
var IList list;
 if(condition)

 list=CacheManagement.GetFromCache();
 else
 list=SqlManagement.GetFromSql();


 list.removeall(x=>x.id==1);
 //end of my function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So when you make a change to list, it is reflected to the cache, that is because the reference (memory address of the list) is copied to cache, so any changes would actually be reflected in the cache.

To avoid it simply put a `Clone()` of your list to the cache. (assuming `UpdateCache()` is the method that sets the cache) you can do it like this:

```
UpdateCache(list.Clone());
```

Comment: no sir you understand me false maybe my explaining is wrong sorry.I am only getting list from cache and editing in code.I never update my cache after edit.UPDATE! I have update my question it was wrong.

Comment: so thats why when you load from cache it comes back. I know Turkish if you like we can continue discussion in chat

Comment: I would be very pleased.Please.

Comment: When you get the object from memory cache you are editing the actual object in the cache not a copy of it. this is why when you remove in the code you are removing the item from the list in the cache as well. this is happening just for the memory cache (heap memory) and careful if you have more than one server at the production line you will loose the consistency on the cache.